How to replace two lines containing [tab] chars into one line with just [newline] char, using a bash script?
In a directory I have a bunch of text files. Some of the files contain double lines with a [tab] char only. I want to find and change these two "tabbed lines" into one line with a new line char.
Example:
[tab]filename: berlin.dat
[tab]city name: Berlin
[tab]city localized name: Berlin
[tab]
[tab]
[tab]country: Germany

Some files may look as above but I want them all to look like this:
[tab]filename: berlin.dat
[tab]city name: Berlin
[tab]city localized name: Berlin
[newline]
[tab]country: Germany

I need check each file if it contains double lines with [tab] char each.
NOTE1: [tab] and [newline] are chars ("\t" and "\n") not texts.
NOTE2: The lines with [tab] chars are in different places of files (before and after different texts).

What should happen if we encounter only a single line containing just a tab?

What should happen if we encounter a sequence of more than two tabs?

Have you tried anything yourself to fix these tunes?

a line containing a [newline]... Do you mean empty line?

In general each line (including the last line) shall be terminated by a newline character, but you did not denote all the characters [newline] consistently; which kinda makes me suspect there is also an "invisible" newline character after this explicit [newline] of yours. But probably not: the line with [newline] is actually exactly one empty line terminated with newline and this is the newline you emphasized (despite of not emphasizing terminating newlines elsewhere); right? It is not a newline "terminated with" another newline (so actually two empty lines). Please confirm.

Can you give us a little more specificity? Does the line before the offending first tab always start with \tcity localized name? Does the line after the offending second tab always start with \tcountry? Thx.

@Chris Davies good questions. In both cases [TAB]s should be removed and line should contain only [newline] char.

@Chris Davies yes, i was trying to use sed but without any results. Later, after @Stephane Chazelas suggesti9n od usingsed -n l file I realized that files contain '\r\n'.

@Fravadona yes, i mean empty line.

@Kamil Maciorowski that's right! Anyway, in the example i wanted to point that the linę with just a [newline] char doesn't contain any other chars.

Great. Please update your question to include the additional clarifications. You don't need to start a new block with the weird "edit"; just incorporate the detail as if you had provided it in the first place (everyone can see you've edited the question, and what you've changed)

It sounds like you want to remove all occurrences of a TAB at the start of the line followed by NL followed by a TAB at the end of the next line, which could be done with:
perl -0777 -p -i.back -e 's/^\t\n\t$//mg' ./*.txt

With -i.back, the files are edited in-place with the original saved with a .back extension. Change to -i to edit in-place without backup.
On your sample (using sed -n l to as to make the TAB and ends of lines visible):
$ sed -n l your-file.txt
\tfilename: berlin.dat$
\tcity name: Berlin$
\tcity localized name: Berlin$
\t$
\t$
\tcountry: Germany$
$ perl -0777 -p -i.back -e 's/^\t\n\t$//mg' your-file.txt

$ sed -n l your-file.txt
\tfilename: berlin.dat$
\tcity name: Berlin$
\tcity localized name: Berlin$
$
\tcountry: Germany$


Edit
As it turns out, your file also has a CR character at the end of each line, most probably because it comes from the Microsoft world where the line delimiter is the CR, LF sequence (\r\n) instead of just LF (aka NL, \n, newline), so that would need to be adapted (here allowing either Unix or Microsoft line delimiters) to:
perl -0777 -p -i.back -e 's/^\t\r?\n\t\r?$//mg' ./*.txt


Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. :( I tried before sed with similar options, but couldn't get any results.  I only get some results when I use 's/^\t\t/\n/g' but it changes all occurences of TAB in my files.

@ludvick it works for me on what I understand your sample to contain (see edit). Please edit your question to include the output of sed -n l your-file.txt so we can confirm what it contains.

In particular sed 's/^\t\t/\n/g' can only change a sequence of two tab characters at the start of each line (the g being redundant as it can only match once per line), not replace all TABs for which you'd need tr '\t' '\n' or sed 's/\t/\n/g' (the latter non-standard).

when I use sed -n l file.txt it shows there are \t\r instead of \t\n (files are from windows). Anyway modyfying the command to perl -0777 -p -i.back -e 's/^\t\r\t$//mg' your-file.txt it still doesn't give any result.

@EdMorton, with the multiline flag, ^ and $ do mean start and end of line.

Oh, must be a PCRE-ism I guess (right up there with . not meaning "any character" for "helping" with clarity), OK thanks for the heads up, deleting my comments now.

@EdMorton, PCRE is a library that was written in the late 90s to bring perl's regexps outside of perl. Here, I'm using the real thing (the P in PCRE), and its s/pattern/replacement/flag. The m flag translates to the PCRE2_MULTILINE flag of pcre2's (the successor of pcre which is now deprecated) pcre2_compile, though it's also possible to enable flags within the perl/pcre2 syntax as in (?m). See perldoc perlop, perldoc perlre, man pcre2_compile, man pcre2pattern for details.

Thanks for the info. I'm just baffled by the mindset of the tool providers that decided to have ., ^, and $ in their regexps, like BREs and EREs, but then have them mean different things depending on how some flags are set. They weren't shy about introducing escape sequences so why not have \N mean "anything but newline" instead of deciding . means that in some contexts and then you need to write the wacky [\s\S] to get the "normal" meaning of ., and similarly for ^ and $. It's like obfuscation was a goal of the language design.

@EdMorton, it's the multi-line mode, so you can use the same regexp in multi-line context. perl also has separate operators to match beginning/end of subject unconditionally. And look around operators which you can use to implement beginning/end of any sort of record.

@EdMorton For . to also match the line delimiter, that's the s flag. Remember that in perl's sed mode (perl -n / perl -p), the line delimiter is included in the pattern space (which IMO is an improvement over sed/awk (though gawk's RT helps even if  clunkier)), so having . match newline there would be undesirable. And you can use the -l option and the s flag for it to behave more like sed.

Yup, perl certainly has no shortage of flags impacting what any given script might mean. FWIW I think always keeping the line delimiter in a separate variable like RT is clearest/simplest since I never have to think about whether or not $0 contains the delimiter, it simply does not, and I never have to wonder if I have the line ending available or not, I simply always do in RT, but I never use perl so I can't say for sure if I'd get used to and eventually prefer sometimes having the line ending in $0 if I used it over time, though I strongly suspect I would not.

Including the NL/record separator in $_ has the annoying feature that if you try to split the line/record, the last field includes the separator even though it probably shouldn't be a part of it. OTOH, if you glue lines together, it's more consistent to have all the NLs in the "work space", instead of all but the last one...

The oddest thing about Perl RE flags is that using /sm for single-line-multi-line mode is just ok, i.e. they're not alternatives to each other.

@ilkkachu IMO, it's more useful to remember that s causes . to match even newline (as useful when matching a single string, not treating newline specially) and m causes ^ and $ to match at the start and end of lines in the subject (as useful when matching within lines a multiline strings), and regard single and muti line as just mnemonics. There are cases where s alone is useful (like when matching file names), m alone is useful, and ms is useful (like when matching strings that span several lines but may be anchored at one of those lines).

Using GNU sed for -E (for EREs to use ?) and -z (to read the whole input file at once, assuming no NULs in the input):
$ sed -Ez 's/(^|\n)(\t(\r?\n)){2}/\1\3/' file
        filename: berlin.dat
        city name: Berlin
        city localized name: Berlin

        country: Germany

The \r? in the regexp and the capture group referenced by \3 in the replacement is to allow for possible DOS line endings. The (^|\n) is to ensure the regexp only matches at the start of a line.

Note that GNU sed's -z is not the equivalent of perl's -0777 (also -g in newer versions) for the slurp mode, it's about reading NUL-delimited records (like -0 in perl).

True, I added a note about that now thanks.

This should be POSIX-compatible (but tested with GNU sed), doesn't use Perl, and doesn't read the whole file at once:
sed -n '/^  $/{H;x;/    .   /{s/.*//;x;s/.*//;n};x};p' $inputfile

(note that all three white spaces are a single literal tab byte; stackexchange seems to lower them to spaces).
This uses sed's "hold space" feature to detect two consecutive lines consisting of just the tab and newline, then replace them with an empty line; singular tab-then-newline lines are not affected. There's probably a better way to write it.
Typescript:
$ cat -A a
^Ifilename: berlin.dat$
^Icity name: Berlin$
^I$
^Icity localized name: Berlin$
^I$
^I$
^Icountry: Germany$
$ sed -n '/^    $/{H;x;/    .   /{s/.*//;x;s/.*//;n};x};p' a | cat -A
^Ifilename: berlin.dat$
^Icity name: Berlin$
^I$
^Icity localized name: Berlin$
$
^Icountry: Germany$

